# How to export an HTML in flexdashboard so other people whithout R can visualize it?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, flexdashboard

I am new to dashboards in R, I used flexdashboard to make one and it gives me the option to export it to HTML but as it is a local document only I can view it. How can I make others who do not have R downloaded to view my dashboard? (And if there is any way to put a password, it would also be very useful) Thank you

Comment: The only solution is to host it on an online server.

Comment: This would probably be better asked in the Rstudio help forum. At the moment it is too unfocussed for a good answer.

Comment: If you don't use shiny in your flexdashboard, you can share the html file to anyone (by email for example). They can view it by opening it in their web browser. Note: for more complex dashboard, you might need to share other resource files as well.